# Отличие статической библиотеки *.lib от заголовочного файла *.h

Tags: c, библиотеки, c++

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос, чем отличается заголовочный файл от статической библиотеки? Если функции у них одинаковые, то почему тогда в файлы .h включают только заголовки, а не функции/классы целиком? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Чтобы не показывать вам исходные тексты/не расходовать ваше дисковое пространство. И не занимать время вашего процессора на трансляцию исходников каждый раз (если вы не храните объектные файлы/библиотеки).

Comment: Про то что не показывать исходники понял, а можно подробнее пожалуйста про последние 2 пункта.

Comment: Исходные тексты как правило (но это зависит от кода, да и от языка) занимают места больше, чем объектные. И для преобразования их в объектный код (трансляцию) требуется время. Поэтому давным-давно (вероятно ещё в 50е годы) и придумали раздельную трансляцию. Хранятся на носители объектные модули (и/или библиотеки) которые надо только подключить к вашей программе на стадии сборки (линковки). Хотя время от времени выплывают какие-то системы спец. назначения (напр. для работы студентов), где об. файлы отсутствуют (скажем скорость трансляции высокая а библиотек мало). Но это редкость.

Comment: @alexlz, у меня некоторые модули на С++ занимают 2-3 кб, а в скомпилированном виде - 15-20 кб.

Comment: @mikillskegg Бывает. А нефиг. Пишите на ассемблере.

Comment: @alexlz, ржу не могу.

Comment: >у меня некоторые модули на С++ занимают 2-3 кб, а в скомпилированном виде - 15-20 кб.

 Ты не считаешь включаемые файлы. С ними у тебя модули будут занимать мегабайты.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Включать определения функций в заголовочные файлы - очень плохой стиль программирования, поскольку если эта функция не будет содержать модификатор static, она будет автоматически рассматриваться как внешняя, общая для всех модулей. А если вы включите один хедер в несколько модулей (вполне обычная картина)? Тогда линковщик выдаст ошибку и будет прав, поскольку не может в одном исполняемом файле быть несколько внешних функций с одним именем.

Если же одну и ту же функцию в хедере сделать статической, то в каждом модуле она будет компилироваться заново -> бездарный расход памяти.

Поэтому лучше используемые разными модулями функции определять в одном модуле как внешние, а в другие включать их декларации, как того требуют правила С/С++. А статические библиотеки - это те же модули с разными функциями, только скомпилированные для удобства и быстроты компиляции всего проекта.

Comment: Я основным вопросом ясно, и можно я задам вопрос не по теме, вы сказали что если написать функции в заголовочном файле то она будет внешняя и доступна для всех модулей, то есть в проекте может быть больше одного модуля если да то где это используется и как эти модули между собой взаимодействуют, и дайте ссылку где можно подробно про программы скомпилированные более чем из одного модуля.

Comment: Нужно для упорядочения больших программ, чтобы не пихать все в один огромный файл, в котором хрен что найдешь, а разбить на несколько модулей, где функции или классы объединяются, как правило, по тематике (хотя это, конечно, не обязательно). Взаимодействуют друг с другом при помощи внешних функций и переменных, которые в других файлах объявляются при помощи тех же хедеров. К тому же, если в программе много модулей, программа большая, то общая компиляция может занять много времени. Если вносите изменения в одну фунцкию, то не нужно перекомпилировать все, достаточно один модуль.

Comment: Прочитать можно в любой книге по С или С++

Comment: Кроме static ещё есть inline. Функции, определённые прямо в классе тоже inline. На них компоновщик ругаться не будет.

Comment: @username76, когда здесь говорилось о модулях, то имелись в виду единицы компиляции (исходные и получаемые из них объектные (\*.o) файлы) их которых компоновщик (линкер) делает загрузочный модуль (\*.exe в Windows).

Надо различать (видимо по контексту) о каких модулях идет речь. Обычно при исполнении модули в смысле единиц компиляции будут работать в одном пространстве памяти, тогда как загрузочные модули в разных (и  невидимых друг для друга.

Comment: @GLmonster, с этим С++ и классами и методами вообще что-то очень странное и интересное. Я имел в виду случай  С, без ООП.

Answer (score 6):

lib - это бинарный файл, в нем находится уже скомпилированный код. Поэтому например стандартные библиотеки не компилируются заново каждый раз при компиляции какого-нибудь хелло-ворлда. .h - текстовый файл, в нем объявлены функции из lib, но самого кода функций в них нет. Подключение файла .h необходимо чтобы компилятор знал как выглядят функции в .lib: какие параметры они принимают (и в каком порядке) и какие значения возвращают.